# How to solve Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'TABLE_PLEDGES' (T_STRING)

Tags: php, android, sql, database, syntax-error

I'm connecting my SQL database to an Android App. I have created and connected the database already so I'm trying to connect this php file now. I'm getting this - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'TABLE_PLEDGES' (T_STRING) on line 13

```
$name = $_GET[‘name’];
$emailAddress = $_GET[‘emailAddress’];
$phoneNumber = $_GET[‘phoneNumber’];
$amount = $_GET[‘amount’];
$date = $_GET[‘date’];

if($name == ‘’ || $emailAddress == ‘’ || $phoneNumber == ‘’ || $amount == ‘’ || $date == “”){
    echo ‘yes’;
}else{
    _once(‘dbConnect.php’);
    $sql = “SELECT * FROM TABLE_PLEDGES WHERE name=‘$name’ OR emailAddress=‘$emailAddress’”;

    $check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_($con,$sql));

    if(isset($check)){
        echo ‘name or email already exist’;
    }else{
        $sql = “INSERT INTO TABLE_PLEDGES (name,emailAddress,phoneNumber,amount, date) VALUES(‘$name’,’$emailAddress’,’$phoneNumber’,’$amount’,’$date’)”;
    if(mysqli_($con,$sql)){
        echo ‘pledge accepted’;
    }else{
        echo ‘oops! Please try again!’;
    }
}
mysqli_close($con);
}
```

Can anyone assist?

Comment: Instead of using quotes you used backtrack.  use quotes and your problem will gone

Comment: Quit using a windows based text editor. It is using *bad* quotes and this is causing your code to fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using quotes you used backtrack. use quotes and your problem will gone

```
<?php
$name = $_GET["name"];
$emailAddress = $_GET["emailAddress"];
$phoneNumber = $_GET["phoneNumber"];
$amount = $_GET["amount"];
$date = $_GET["date"];

if($name == "" || $emailAddress == "" || $phoneNumber == "" || $amount == "" || $date == ""){
    echo "yes";
}else{
    require_once("dbConnect.php"); //instead of _once it will be require_once
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE_PLEDGES WHERE name="$name" OR emailAddress="$emailAddress"";

    $check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_($con,$sql));

    if(isset($check)){
        echo "name or email already exist";
    }else{
        $sql = "INSERT INTO TABLE_PLEDGES (name,emailAddress,phoneNumber,amount, date) VALUES("$name","$emailAddress","$phoneNumber","$amount","$date")";
    if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){ // instead of mysqli_ it will be mysqli_query
        echo "pledge accepted";
    }else{
        echo "oops! Please try again!";
    }
}
mysqli_close($con);
}
```

Comment: Hi Guys, I found the solution to the above error. Some text editors doesn't recognize the language so I corrected as given by A-2-A. Thanks for the assistance again!

Comment: @Avant Thanks for assistance. I'm just seeing this. I will follow your instructions on marking it as answer and up vote. Thank you again for the help.

Comment: @HowardBritton  welcome :))